# Reverse proxy FTP traffic to Docker containers based on hostaname?

Tags: ftp, reverse-proxy, docker

Is there any way to reverse proxy FTP (or SFTP) connections as you can do with HTTP traffic? I already have working setup fot HTTP connections with [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) and I was wondering if I can route the FTP connections in similar way:

```
User connects ftp.domain1.com --> FTP proxy --> container1 (with -e HOST=ftp.domain1.com)
User connects ftp.domain2.com --> FTP proxy --> container2 (with -e HOST=ftp.domain2.com)
```

And both of the containers are running in the same machine and have the same IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because those protocols lack an in-band way of signalling the name of the host they wish to connect to (cf HTTP's `Host` request header).

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if it's time for a canonical question about hostname-unaware services, and how you can't proxy/redirect/frotz them based on the hostname that was looked up by the client?

Comment: It's long overdue, IMO.